# Can I reuse content across sites like Medium for SEO purposes?

Tags: blog, copywriting, content-strategy

Is it appropriate to use the same content (or with slight changes) for article submission on websites like Medium for SEO purposes?

Comment: Would you define SEO -- I'm thinking it's some sort of corporate officer position. And you might consider expound on 'websites like medium' since the benefit of that exposure might not be clear to everyone, including myself.

Comment: **Inappropriate** Near-identical articles on different websites *discredits* the information by appearing to be farmed (astroturfed), or to be 'news laundering' where dubious information is quoted from a circle of linked articles to obscure the source. They will be ranked as similar content, and will appear together in searches, making it more obvious. (a better way to boost your legitimacy would be to build up a *series* of articles around the same topic, making you an 'authority') –– There may be other answers if you elaborate on 'appropriate for SEO purposes'

Comment: Oh …. Search Engine Optimization SEO.  That doesn’t seem to fit with this forums purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your article's content which is uploaded on your website does not contain the exact same wording when you publish it on any other sites, such as Medium, LinkedIn, or similar. You will need to change the content's wording.

If you publish the exact same article on other websites, it will be witnessed as duplicated content in the eyes of Google, and you may get duplicated error in Google search console.

So, make sure to either paraphrase it or change the information, just make it similar.

Comment: Firstly, I'm struggling to parse what you mean by "you may get duplicated error and Google search console". Are you saying that posting the exact same content on multiple websites will actually *harm* your SEO? (Somebody ought to tell the spammers that...) Secondly, can you provide a source to back this claim up?

Comment: @F1Krazy That is common SEO knowledge. It's even on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_content

Comment: Well, someone *seriously* ought to tell the spammers that, then...